# SQL get data from the table only if it doesn't exist in another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Suppose that we have a table `Users` that stores basic info about users

```
    UserId  FirstName   LastName
    1       Maria       Anders
    2       Ana         Trujillo
    3       Antonio     Moreno
    4       Thomas      Hardy
    5       Christina   Berglund
    6       Hanna       Moos
    7       Frédérique  Citeaux
    8       Martín      Sommer
```

we have two tables `Details` and `Exception` that store additional details about users, actually both tables have the same structure

`Details` table

```
UserId  Age
1       10
2       10
3       10
4       40
5       50
6       60
7       70
8       80
```

`Excpetions` table

```
UserId  Age
 1      100
 2      100
 3      100
```

I want to write query to get all details about the users from `Exceptions` and `details`, if the user has info stored in the `exceptions` table it should override data stored in `details` table otherwise get the data from `details` table
so the result should be

```
UserId  FirstName   LastName    Age
1       Maria         Anders    100
2       Ana         Trujillo    100
3       Antonio       Moreno    100
4       Thomas         Hardy    40
5       Christina    Berglund   50
6       Hanna           Moos    60
7       Frédérique    Citeaux   70
8       Martín        Sommer    80
```

so in this example Maria , Ana and Antonio with Ids 1 , 2 , 3 have ages 10 in the `details` table but becuase their data stored in `excpetions` table the result should show Age 100, for other users the don't have information in the `excpetion` table so simply we get the data from `details` table.

actually, I came up with a solution but I think there is better query I can write, here is my solution

```
select u.UserId, u.FirstName , u.LastName , e.Age from Exceptions e

inner join Users u on u.UserId = e.UserId

union select  u.UserId, u.FirstName , u.LastName , d.Age from Details d

inner join Users u on u.UserId = d.UserId

where d.UserId not in ( select UserId from Exceptions )
```

is there any way to avoid this subquery ? can we do better ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a piar of left join and  CASE WHEN (or a  check for null)

```
select 
   u.UserId
 , u.FirstName 
 , u.LastName 
 , CASE WHEN e.Age IS NOT NULL  then e.age ELSE d.age END  as AGE
from Users u 
left join Details as d on .UserId = d.UserId 
left join Exceptions e on e.UserId = u.UserId
```

Comment: just pasted the exact query. but you are faster!

Comment: @Badiparmagi   then you are good at sql .. could be you can improved the answer  and then post .. (using isnull .. or others.. )

Comment: thanks. maybe you can add an alias  like 'age' in case of 'no column name' naming. good job.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using CASE statement, I did this using COALESCE.

```
select 
   u.UserId
 , u.FirstName 
 ,COALESCE(e.Age,d.age) AGE
from Users u 
left join Details as d on u.UserId = d.UserId 
left join Exceptions e on e.UserId = u.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework and you have your Foreign Keys set up:

```
myDbContext.Users
.Select(u => new
{
    u.UserId,
    u.FirstName,
    u.LastName,
    Age = u.Exceptions.Any() ? u.Exceptions.FirstOrDefault().Age : u.Details.FirstOrDefault().Age
})
```